# Is there any way to write an aspect triggered after execution of a method in an external library in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using Spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE version in my project. There is a maven dependency and I need to realize some extra operations according to result of a certain method in this external library. I created an aspect but it doesn't hit during execution. I have tried this aspect for my own method in my project and this time it hits. So I wonder that am I missing any specific property or annotation to add my aspect or configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Spring AOP can only advice Spring container managed beans. That is the reason advice work for your beans and not for an external class . AspectJ can be used for your usecase

Comment: I recommend you to read the Spring manual. There is a special chapter about [how to use native AspectJ](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) from within Spring.

Comment: Thanks guys, I missed that part.